# Make image hide correctly after filtering using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, filter

I am using the following code to filter data in a table and to display image with id `loader` while doing this.

My problem is that it does not hide and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I tried adding an alert before the hiding and it does show the alert but it's not working properly when it comes to display the image. What am I doing wrong? `inputFilter` is the name of the input for the filter and `data_fm_op` is the name of the table.

**JavaScript**

```js
$('#inputFilter').change(function () {
$('#loader').show();
var that = this;
$('tbody tr').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf($(that).val()) == -1) {
        $('#data_fm_op').animate({
            marginTop: 0
        }, 50, function () {
            $(this).find('tbody tr').eq(i).hide();
        });
    } else {
        $('#data_fm_op').animate({
            marginTop: 0
        }, 50, function () {
            $(this).find('tbody tr').eq(i).show();
        });
    }
});
$('#loader').hide();
```

});

**Here is the jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/m6hLR/

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Subin here: http://jsfiddle.net/m6hLR/

Comment: something like this [http://jsfiddle.net/m6hLR/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/m6hLR/10/)

Comment: @AbrahamUribe great! you should post it as an answer! that fixed my problem!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wait on the animate callback and if the current index is equal to the length of tr then hide the loader

```
$('#loader').hide();   
$('#inputFilter').change(function() {
    $('#loader').show();
    var that = this;
    var length=$('tbody tr').length;
    $('tbody tr').each(function(i,n) {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf($(that).val()) == -1) {
            $('#data_fm_op').animate({
                marginTop: 0
            }, 50, function() {
                $(this).hide();
                if(i==length-1){//if it is the last element hide the loader
                     $('#loader').hide();           
                }  
            });
        } else {
            $('#data_fm_op').animate({
                marginTop: 0
            }, 50, function() {
                $(this).show();
                if(i==length-1){//if it is the last element hide the loader
                     $('#loader').hide();           
            }  
       });
      }           
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m6hLR/10/

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard without a jsfiddle with some HTML to understand the structure of your code but try this instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/MRa8q/3/

```
$('#inputFilter').change(function() {
        $('#loader').show();
        var that = this;
        $('tbody tr').each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf($(that).val()) == -1) {
                $('#data_fm_op').animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                }, 50, function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
            } else {
                $('#data_fm_op').animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                }, 50, function() {
                    $(this).show();
                });
            }
        });
    $('#loader').hide();
});
```

Comment: I added a jsFiddle with some details

Answer (score 0):

You have not added an **id** attribute on image tag. Change :

```
<img src="https://www.vocalware.com/images/ajax_loader.gif" height="19" width="19">
```

to :

```
<img src="https://www.vocalware.com/images/ajax_loader.gif" id="loader" height="19" width="19">
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/subins2000/m6hLR/7/

Comment: Oops... Just fixed it

Comment: I still have the problem though

Comment: Nope, it only hides it. It should show while it looks for the data and then hide when it stops... Let me make the table longer to show you what I mean

Comment: Look: Try filtering and looking for 1 http://jsfiddle.net/m6hLR/9/ it's not filtering right